# Java static method synchronization on Class or Method level?

Tags: java, multithreading

In order to protect the shared resource (HashMap things), the following class synchronizes 2 methods. However, it appears that 2 different threads can act such as Thread 1 enters getThing() while thread 2 enters dispatchThings(). In other words, being static methods, is the mutex on the Class object or somehow on the Class Method? i.e. is the "things" collection safe from concurrency errors?

```
    class ThingMgr {

            static Map<Integer, Thing> things = new HashMap<>();

            static synchronized Thing getThing(long id) {
                Thing t = things.get(d);
                if (null == t) {
                    t = new Thing(id);
                    things.put(id, t);
                }
                return t;
            }

            static synchronized int dispatchThings() {
                for (Thing t : things) {
                    if (t.isReady) t.dispatch();
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: No, the mutex is the class. Your diagnostic is probably wrong. Or you load this class in two separate classloaders.

Comment: @JBNizet You're correct. I accept your comment by bumping it. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If only the given two methods access the `things` collection, then it is safe for concurrent use.

`static synchronized` methods synchronize on the `class` itself, in your case is essentially equivalent to `synchronized (ThingMgr.class) { ... }`.

Answer (score -1):

It make sense to synchronize method ***getThing(..)***, it will protect from creating the same "thing" in the map.

But regard the second method,
it depends on your logic:

- if it's possible to dispatch all "Things" in parallel - remove the
  sync
- if the Things list can be dispatched multiple times, but not in parallel - sync is good
- if the list can be dispatched only one time - the sync will not
  help you, should be limited by another way

Comment: The second method **must** be synchronized. Iterating on a non-threadsafe map that is mutable by another thread without synchronization wouldn't be safe.